# KeyError: '[datetime.time(12, 19, 29) not in index'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

data is in epoch nanoseconds as below the sample shows:

```
time               duration
1.530706769E+018    40000000000
1.53070683E+018     41000000000
1.530706891E+018    41000000000
1.530706951E+018    41000000000
1.530707011E+018    41000000000
1.530707068E+018    37000000000
1.530707128E+018    41000000000
1.530707188E+018    41000000000
1.530707248E+018    40000000000
1.530707313E+018    45000000000
1.530707368E+018    40000000000
1.530707432E+018    44000000000
1.530707492E+018    44000000000
1.530707552E+018    44000000000
1.530707612E+018    39000000000
1.530707673E+018    41000000000
1.530707729E+018    37000000000
1.530712952E+018    45000000000
1.530713007E+018    40000000000
1.530713067E+018    35000000000
1.530713132E+018    40000000000
1.530713187E+018    36000000000
1.530713248E+018    36000000000
1.530713308E+018    40000000000
1.530713369E+018    41000000000
1.530713429E+018    40000000000
1.53071349E+018     41000000000
1.530713551E+018    42000000000
1.530713611E+018    40000000000
1.530713671E+018    40000000000
1.530713732E+018    40000000000
1.530713792E+018    39000000000
1.530713852E+018    39000000000
1.530713913E+018    40000000000
1.530713973E+018    40000000000
1.530714029E+018    36000000000
1.53071409E+018     36000000000
1.530714151E+018    41000000000
1.530714212E+018    41000000000
1.530714272E+018    41000000000
1.530714332E+018    40000000000
1.530714393E+018    41000000000
1.530714454E+018    41000000000
1.530714515E+018    42000000000
1.530714574E+018    39000000000
1.53071463E+018     39000000000
1.530714694E+018    44000000000
1.530714753E+018    40000000000
1.530714814E+018    41000000000
1.530714874E+018    42000000000
1.530714934E+018    41000000000
1.530714995E+018    41000000000
1.530715056E+018    41000000000
1.530715112E+018    37000000000
1.530715245E+018    16000000000
1.530715275E+018    15000000000
1.530715305E+018    15000000000
1.530715335E+018    15000000000
1.530715366E+018    16000000000
1.530715396E+018    15000000000
1.530715427E+018    16000000000
1.530715456E+018    15000000000
1.530715487E+018    16000000000
1.530715517E+018    15000000000
1.530715548E+018    16000000000
1.530715578E+018    15000000000
```

To transform I used code in pandas as:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import datetime from datetime

df = pd.read_csv('d1.csv')

df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='ns')

df['Time'] = df['time'].dt.time
```

Above codes transforms data as in form:

```
df.head(20)
Out[100]: 
              time             d      Time
0  2018-07-04 12:19:29  4.000000e+10  12:19:29
1  2018-07-04 12:20:30  4.100000e+10  12:20:30
2  2018-07-04 12:21:31  4.100000e+10  12:21:31
3  2018-07-04 12:22:31  4.100000e+10  12:22:31
4  2018-07-04 12:23:31  4.100000e+10  12:23:31
5  2018-07-04 12:24:28  3.700000e+10  12:24:28
6  2018-07-04 12:25:28  4.100000e+10  12:25:28
7  2018-07-04 12:26:28  4.100000e+10  12:26:28
8  2018-07-04 12:27:28  4.000000e+10  12:27:28
9  2018-07-04 12:28:33  4.500000e+10  12:28:33
10 2018-07-04 12:29:28  4.000000e+10  12:29:28
11 2018-07-04 12:30:32  4.400000e+10  12:30:32
12 2018-07-04 12:31:32  4.400000e+10  12:31:32
13 2018-07-04 12:32:32  4.400000e+10  12:32:32
14 2018-07-04 12:33:32  3.900000e+10  12:33:32
15 2018-07-04 12:34:33  4.100000e+10  12:34:33
16 2018-07-04 12:35:29  3.700000e+10  12:35:29
17 2018-07-04 14:02:32  4.500000e+10  14:02:32
18 2018-07-04 14:03:27  4.000000e+10  14:03:27
19 2018-07-04 14:04:27  3.500000e+10  14:04:27
```

Now I need a scatter plot between `Time` and `d` 
   So I coded as:

```
x = df['Time']

y = df['d']

df.plot(x,y, 'scatter')
```

But got error as:

`KeyError: '[datetime.time(12, 19, 29) datetime.time(12, 20, 30)\n datetime.time(12, 21, 31) ... datetime.time(23, 54, 39)\n datetime.time(23, 55, 16) datetime.time(23, 55, 52)] not in index'`

What this above error means... How to resolve this and get a scatter plot here ?

Comment: Even without that error, you won't be able to use a scatter plot here because your x-axis isn't numeric

Comment: @user3483203 Can't x-axis have a value in `%HH:%MM:%SS` which is a `datetime` object and y axis with a 'float' value ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
df.plot(x='Time', y='d', style=".")
```

Comment: Worked crisply Thanks @Joe

Answer (score 1):

set `time` as index and plot it

```
df = df.set_index('time')
df.d.plot(style='.')
```

Answer (score 0):

[pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter — pandas 0.23.4 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html):

> x : int or str
>
> The column name or column position to be used as horizontal coordinates for each point.
>
> y : int or str
>
> The column name or column position to be used as vertical coordinates for each point.

So, it should be

```
df.plot('Time','d','scatter')
```

Comment: `df.plot('Time','d','scatter')` gives a `ValueError: scatter requires x column to be numeric`.

Comment: @suryarahul Yes, I didn't look any further. That is a problem unrelated to what you asked -- `KeyError: '[datetime.time(12, 19, 29) not in index'`.

Comment: @suryarahul As has been noted on your post itself, Times cannot be used as the x-axis  ... which is exactly what this error is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

### Try matplotlib

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(df['Time'], df['d'])